# Why is my $items doesn't hold a group of $item? Laravel 8 Ecommerce

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8

I'm from the same post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65473730/laravel-8-shopping-cart-item-quantity-wont-increment?noredirect=1#comment115766911_65473730) but I've found the root problem why is my quantity won't increment but I don't know how to solve this. The problem is at my isset function (in Cart.php), because I tried to echo something there and just realized the function isn't running. This is the [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELmpD.jpg) pops up when I removed isset function at the if($this->items). I tried to dd($items) too, and it said null. Why is my $items isn't holding a group of $item? Do you guys know why and how to solve this?

p/s: from the previous post, I've removed my $oldCart and replace it with $cart, and I'm expecting $cart to overwrite itself.
These are all the codes related to my shopping cart.

In Cart.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

class Cart
{
    public $items = array();
    public $totalQty = 0;
    public $totalPrice = 0;


    public function __construct($cart)
    {
        if ($cart) {
            //dd($this);
            $this->items = $cart->items;
            $this->totalQty = $cart->totalQty;
            $this->totalPrice = $cart->totalPrice;
        }
    }


    public function add($item, $id)
    {
        global $cart;
        global $items;

        //default values if item not in cart


        $storedItem = [
            'qty' => 0,
            'price' => $item->price,
            'item' => $item
        ];


        //if item is already in shopping cart
        if ($this->$items) {
            if (array_key_exists($id, $this->items)) {
                $storedItem = $this->items[$id];
            }
        }

        //dd($items);
        $storedItem['qty']++;
        $storedItem['price'] = $item->price * $storedItem['qty'];
        $this->items[$id] = $storedItem;
        $this->totalQty++;
        $this->totalPrice += $item->price;
    }
}
```

in FoodController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Cart;
use App\Models\Food;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;


class FoodController extends Controller
{
public function addtoCart(Request $request, $id, Food $foods)
    {

        $foods = Food::find($id);

        //check in session if cart already contains product
        $cart = Session::has('cart') ? Session::get('cart') : null;

        //dd($cart);
        //if it did contain products, pass them to constructor
        if (!$cart) {
            $cart = new Cart($cart);
        }

        $food = $foods->id;
        $cart->add($foods, $food);

        Session::put('cart', $cart);
        //dd($request->session()->get('cart'));


        return view('cart', ['food' => $cart->items, 'totalPrice' => $cart->totalPrice]);
    }

    public function getCart()
    {
        if (!Session::has('cart')) {
            return view('cart');
        }

        $cart = Session::get('cart');
        $cart = new Cart($cart);
        return view('cart', ['food' => $cart->items, 'totalPrice' => $cart->totalPrice]);
    }
}
```

in cart.blade.php

```
    @foreach ($food as $foods)
                        
                        
       <p align="left"><a href="#"> {{ $foods['item']['name'] }} </a> <span class="price">MYR {{ $foods['price'] }} </span></p>
       <p align="left">Quantity</p>
       <p><input class="w3-input w3-p-adding-16 w3-border" type="number" placeholder="Quantity" value="{{ $foods['qty'] }}" required name="quantity"></p>
                        
@endforeach
                        
                        
<hr>
                        
<p align="left">Total <span class="price"><b>MYR {{ $totalPrice }}</b></span></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to re-define your add function in the Cart class to be like this, there are some syntax errors, (remove `$` sign form `$this->$items`), and there is no need to re-declare $cart & $items in the function

```
public function add($item, $id)
    {
        //default values if item not in cart


        $storedItem = [
            'qty' => 0,
            'price' => $item->price,
            'item' => $item
        ];

        //if item is already in shopping cart
        if (isset($this->items) ? $this->items : false) {
            if (array_key_exists($id, $this->items)) {
                $storedItem = $this->items[$id];
            }
        }

        //dd($items);
        $storedItem['qty']++;
        $storedItem['price'] = $item->price * $storedItem['qty'];
        $this->items[$id] = $storedItem;
        $this->totalQty++;
        $this->totalPrice += $item->price;
    }
```

Comment: it works! Thanks a lot! but what's the difference between $items and $this->items? I don't understand what happen during the error

Comment: welcome, $this->items refers to the current object variable, $items refers to variable declared in the same scope. and you've already initialize object variable in the constructor

Comment: ah I see, I understand now, thank you again for your time :))

Answer (score 0):

The error you get is because of the way you try to get a property from $this cart object.

Change in line 39 (inside the add method):

```
if (isset($this->$items) ? $items : false)
```

To:

```
$this->items
```

Because in the way you currently have it defined, it tries to access a property on $this that has the value of the variable $items,
inside your conditional.

This is also the reason why the error points to Cart::$ since items as a variable holds no value at that point in time.

Comment: the error that i got is after i removed isset. if I add isset in there, I can run my website but i can't get the quantity to increment. I'm sorry about that, I forgot to remove isset at my post.